# Geography/Geometry literal types?

Tags: database, postgresql, gis, postgis

It seems that most databases that support GIS encode the object as a string within a function, such as:

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(110 40, 2 3, -10 80, -7 9)')
```

The one exception I've seen to this is from Postgres directly (and not PostGIS, which uses the above format), for things like:

```
SELECT POINT '1,1';
```

Are geo literals in databases essentially unused, and all 'standard' stuff has moved to within function calls (I suppose Postgres just maintains this feature for historical baggage?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing geographic and geometric data types.

The [`point`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-geometric.html#id-1.5.7.16.5) data type is a native PostgreSQL [`geometric data type`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-geometric.html#id-1.5.7.16.5) designed for two-dimensional spatial objects only. I've never saw a GIS related project that uses geometric data types, as it is pretty limited and makes simple 2D GIS tasks quite hard to implement, e.g. transformation of spatial reference systems.

The LineString in your example is just a [`WKT`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry) (Well Known Text) representation of a spatial object, which comes with the extension [`PostGIS`](https://postgis.net/) - WKT is a OGC (Open Geospatial Consortium) standard. If you're not familiar with OGC, consider it the W3C of GIS ;) If you're interested in the standards itself, take a look at the OGC [`specification`](https://www.ogc.org/standards/sfs) for more details. PostGIS is imho the best GIS support for databases out there! It has loads of quite handy functions that make multidimensional spatial objects manipulation very easy, and most importantly: it has a very active community.

Comment: Thanks -- this is a great answer and appreciate all the links for myself to learn more. About `PostGIS is imho the best GIS support` -- would you consider it better than ArcGIS? That seems like (in my limited usage of a few GIS's) it's by far the most powerful.

Comment: also, have you ever seen a non-GIS project that makes use of Geometric data types?

Comment: @David542 ArcGIS is a geographic information system, whilst PostgreSQL is a relational database. With the extension PostGIS it is possible to perform geospatial operations inside the database. I wouldn't claim that PostGIS can replace ArcGIS, as they have different purposes. But, it is often a bad idea to bring the data to the software ;) So, loading large volumes of that in ArcGIS and then perform spatial operations can be very slow. Sending a query to the database your bringing the software to the data, and that is always the best solution ;) cheers

Comment: @David542 I honestly never met anyone who uses the geometric data types for anything

Answer (score 1):

PostGIS follows the OGC standard, while PostgreSQL's built-in geometry support doesn't. This is largely because it is older and it does not aim to model geography: it exclusively deals with the Euclidian plain.

While PostgreSQL's geometry features are useful for dealing with two-dimensional flat geometry, any real-world geographical application would use PostGIS.

Comment: what would be an actual use case where `PostgreSQL's geometry features are useful for dealing with two-dimensional flat geometry,` ? I've actually never come across a use case of plain geometry -- where is that used in practice?

Comment: What about a program that teaches people Euclidian geometry, lets them draw lines, points and circles and intersect those?

Comment: It is an OGC standard.

Comment: @IanTurton which part do you mean "is an OGC standard" ?

Comment: Originally @LaurenzAlbe said it was an OSGeo standard, but it is actually an OGC standard. OSGeo isn't really in the standards business.